# How to interrupt an uncompleted delay in SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog, delay, system-verilog, cancellation, interruption

I want to apply a different rising and falling delay to a signal using the following code:

```
  timeunit            1ns;
  timeprecision       1ps;
  parameter   real    delay_en_rising_us  = 100.0;    // means 100us
  parameter   real    delay_en_falling_us = 300.0;    // means 300us
  logic en;
  logic en_delayed;
  
  always_comb
    if ($realtime == 0)
      en_delayed = en;
    else if (en)
      en_delayed <= #(delay_en_rising_us*1us) en;
    else
      en_delayed <= #(delay_en_falling_us*1us) en;
```

The Scenario 1 shows the results which are looking good.

[image]

However, if I change the delays like this:

```
parameter   real    delay_en_rising_us  = 100.0;      // means 1000us
parameter   real    delay_en_falling_us = 1500.0;     // means 1500us
```

Then the results are like shown in Scenario 2 which are not what I was expecting and trying to achieve.

[image]

Actually, the falling delay of 1500us at signal "en_delayed" should be immediately canceled or interrupted if the signal "en" goes high. See following picture showing the expected behaviour.

[image]

In summary, if there is a delay which has not completed and the signal "en" suddenly changes then that uncompleted delay should be immediately interrupted.

Thank you very much for any suggestion.

Below is the code for simulation.

```
module top;
  
  timeunit            1ns;
  timeprecision       1ps;

  //--------------------------------------------------------  
  // This is working fine
  parameter   real    delay_en_rising_us  = 100.0;    // means 100us
  parameter   real    delay_en_falling_us = 300.0;    // means 300us

  // This is not working fine or as expected
  //parameter   real    delay_en_rising_us  = 100.0;      // means 1000us
  //parameter   real    delay_en_falling_us = 1500.0;     // means 1500us
  
  logic en;
  logic en_delayed;
  
  //--------------------------------------------------------    
  always_comb
    if ($realtime == 0)
      en_delayed = en;
    else if (en)
      en_delayed <= #(delay_en_rising_us*1us) en;
    else
      en_delayed <= #(delay_en_falling_us*1us) en;
  
  //--------------------------------------------------------    
  //initial begin
  initial fork
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd"); $dumpvars;
    
    //en = 0;
    //#100us  en = 1;       
    //#1000us en = 0; 
    //#3000us en = 1; 

    en = 1;
    #1000us en = 0;
    #2000us en = 1;
    
    #5000us $finish;

  join

 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

endmodule
```

Comment: you should not have rising edge before delay of 1500 is done. Otherwise behavior is undefined. In most cases, however, I saw, rising edge just gets swallowed by simulation. Potentially this is a hardware behavior as well.

Comment: @ Serge: the "en" signal is an input signal i.e. it can change anytime. The idea is that if "en" goes high like shown before delay of 1500 is completed then that delay should be immediately interrupted.

Comment: then you need a different algorith.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need code like below. en_delayed will be 1'b0 at time 0ns in this.

```
always@(posedge en)
  begin   
     en_delayed <=0;
     en_delayed <= #(delay_en_rising_us*1us) 1'b1;
  end   
  always@(negedge en)
  begin
     en_delayed <= 1;
     en_delayed <= #(delay_en_falling_us*1us) 1'b0;
  end
```